# I would like to send multiple data from a form to data base

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here alone with name i want to send msg too.
Is it possible will you plese help.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvF8F.png)

Comment: Can you paste your code here, as text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the code looks right.

When you define `guestbookSendMessage{}` please don't forget to add `,` between 2 elements of input and textarea.